# Is there any way to have Express draw from two file system directories for one web directory?

Tags: node.js, express

Say I want to have an apparent directory that, via the browser, is `http://whatever/images/`

But on the file system, it actually draws from both `/Users/me/www/images` and `/Users/me/moreimages/`. So if I request `http://whatever/images/selfie.jpg`, it will first look for `/Users/me/www/images/selfie.jpeg`, and if that isn't found, serve `/Users/me/moreimages/selfie.jpeg` instead.

I can think of some ugly ways of doing this, handling the routing and serving myself, but I'd like to do it in the most "correct" and hopefully straightforward way.  Does express have some workaround where I can cause it to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Just have two instances of [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware.builtin) both mounted on `/images`:

```
router.use('/images', express.static('/Users/me/images/'));
router.use('/images', express.static('/Users/me/moreimages/'));
```

If the request is not satisfied in the first instance of the middleware, the second one will be processed, and so on.

Comment: i think the first one `express.static` middleware will just send 404, and will not pass the request to the next `express.static` middleware

Comment: Cool, i didn't know this was possible. +1.

Comment: @vodolaz095 Not true, otherwise any routes you have after `express.static` in the middleware chain would never execute.

Comment: Nice it works.  I swear I tried that but must have made a mistake. :)